# How to check if a program is running in different server using vb.net and cmd

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd

I need to check if any program is running in a different server for which I have the access.

For example:
Server name: `remoteServer.xyz.com`
Application: `Notepad.exe`

From my machine as admin I'm able to access `remoteServer.xyz.com`
So how I can check if `Notepad.exe` is running in `remoteServer.xyz.com`
Using `vb.net` and `cmd`

I used following code

```
Dim p As Process = New Process()
Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
pi.Arguments = "tasklist /s remoteServer.xyz.com"
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()
```

but this just opens a command prompt, does not pass the argument and execute

Comment: [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) can connect to a reachable machine in the network and list its [running processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process). It can also raise events when a process is started or closed. See [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-on-a-remote-computer) and also [WMI Command-line Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-command-line-tools) (not needed in a VB.Net app).

Comment: The Windows `TASKLIST` command can connect to remote computers and tell you if notepad is running on that computer.  Read the help on Microsoft's site for the command or open up a command prompt and type: `tasklist /?` I am betting you will see what you need.

Comment: `tasklist /S remoteServer.xyz.com /U domain\username /NH | findstr /i "notepad.exe"`

Comment: @Gerhard That worked perfectly when I manually ran the command in CMD.
But same I tried in vb.net and it just opens a command prompt for me but doesn't pass the arguments

Following is my code
Dim p As Process = New Process()
Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
pi.Arguments = "tasklist /S remoteServer.xyz.com | findstr /i 'notepad.exe'"
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()

Comment: It is not a vb.net command, that is a commands initiated from cmd or batch file.